# Database with Multi Master replication

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, multi-master-replication

What are good options for a multi master replication enabled, scalable database. We are talking about 15-16 TB of data. We are thinking DynamoDB. Are there any more databases which we should look up.
Any advice on DynamoDB usage as well as new ideas about the required database type is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, DynamoDB supports cross-region replication with the [cross-region replication library](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-cross-region-library) on Github. It should be somewhat straightforward to divide up the partition and sort key space by region and then run the library in each region. You would have to modify the library to ignore stream records for items that are not mastered in the region (each region should only propagate changes for items mastered in that region). In this setup, each master-replica table in each region will have a stream enabled and each region should have an EC2 instance processing that table's DynamoDB stream.

Comment: Now you don't need any lib or EC2 instances. Just set up a table, add regions to it and it will do all the thing to distribute to multiple regions. To make table global you need an **empty** table with streams **enabled** and AWS does the rest.